# How to render/ format axes each 6 month with d3.scaleTime?

Tags: d3.js, data-visualization

I am trying to make chart like [this](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4b66c0d9be9a0d56484e), using d3.js v.4. But data that i have is twice each year, differ with the given example. How to render axes for every 6 month? My data is every February, and August for each year (2008-2015).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set your x line with scaleTime and startDate and endDate
when you create an axis you can pass an [`interval` with filter](https://github.com/d3/d3-time#interval_filter) to [tick func](https://github.com/d3/d3-axis/blob/master/README.md#axis_ticks).
If needed you can also format the axis tick with [tickFormat](https://github.com/d3/d3-axis/blob/master/README.md#axis_tickFormat).

Here the example using coffeescript

```
timeParse= d3.timeParse('%m-%Y');
startDate= timeParse('02-2008');
endDate= timeParse('08-2015');
x= d3.scaleTime()
  .domain d3.extent d3.timeMonth.range startDate, endDate, 6
  .range [0, 700];
xAxis= d3.axisBottom(x)
  .ticks d3.timeMonth.filter (xDate)->
    # january is 00
    # console.log 'getMonth: ', xDate.getMonth();
    if xDate.getMonth() is 1 or xDate.getMonth() is 7
      true;
    else
      false;
  .tickFormat d3.timeFormat '%b %Y';

svg.append 'g'
  .attr 'class', 'axis-group'
  .attr 'transform', "translate(0, 300)"
  .call  xAxis;
```

output: 
[image: use text anchor start]

Note the that the stop range are excluded as describe [here](https://github.com/d3/d3-time#interval_range)

Reference:

1. [Month Axis](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1849162)